# Is there some kind of 'Dynamic' Enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an “abstract” enum in a .NET class library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030911/how-can-i-make-an-abstract-enum-in-a-net-class-library)

So, here is my project.

I have a network framework that has a enum called command.  This basically tells the system if the packet that just came in is a CONNECT, CHAT, JOIN, etc.  As a future step, I want to allow plugins to use this 'framework' which could provide additional command types.  I know you can't add values to existing enum's in the subsequent plugins, so what would be the proper way to do what I want to do above?  A Class?  just an integer field for command, and a series of const int's like CONNECT = 1, JOIN = 2, etc?

Comment: Focus on implementing *behavior*.  Code, not data.

Comment: In my opinion there is no need to create an extendable command structure. The commands can simply be constants in your network framework. And plugins should be free to implement their commands any which way they like. If you want to define contracts for how commands should be created/handled, then use an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have one of your main message types as `plugin`, so that you can delegate handling the message to the plugin itself, rather than trying to deal with these currently-unknown packets yourself. Additionally, each plugin message should include an identifier that specifies which plugin should handle it.

In general, you to make the plugin system as modular as possible, so you don't have to worry about how it will interfere with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to create a class with constants

```
public class Commands
{
    public const int CONNECT = 1;
    public const int CHAT = 2;
    public const int JOIN = 3;
}
```

When user want to add new command types, he will need to override this class

```
public class PluginCommands: Commands
{
    public const int AddBuddy = 4;
    public const int Disconnect = 5;
}
```

Comment: Ideally a solution would be typesafe.